# Change style to match another element's style after load and change of the styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with this code. I want the text color to be the same as the background color of the div, so that I could use the invert functionality of css. I want it to be changeable dynamically. I tried changing the trigger from onload to onmouseover, which works but it doesn't make sense.

Is there a way I could get this to work as onload and also when I change the background color of the div with for example Chrome Inspection?

```js
function getColor() {
  document.getElementById('text1').style.color = document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor;
}
```

```html
 <div id="div1" onload="getColor();" style="background-color: #fff">
    <h1 id="text1" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
```

Comment: If you want this kind of effects you can use `mix-blend-mode` in css ,

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

Comment: ^ note that this isn't very widely supported yet. https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: Okay, thanks, guys. I still don't understand why people would downvote this question. I mean I know it is not that smart and hard, but it is my question and I barely have 11 reputation points....

Comment: The help text for a downvote says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I wouldn't take it too personally; one person didn't find your question clear or helpful. It isn't a reflection on you, just someone's opinion of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instaed use function set it in JS without function and remove   `onload="getColor();"`,it will done when JS load

```js
var color= document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById('text1').style.color =color;
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #fff">
  <h1 id="text1" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
   </div>
```

EDIT!
You can do it in css:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

```css
#text1,#text2,#text3{
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="background-color: #fff">
  <h1 id="text1" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
</div>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: red">
  <h1 id="text2" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
</div>
<div id="div1" style="background-color: blue">
  <h1 id="text3" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually want to make that dynamic so if I change the background color with another script, then it will be applied automatically.

Comment: so use css `mix-blend`

Comment: @לבנימלכה be careful because mix-blend-mode isn't widely supported right now.  caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getColor() {
 document.getElementById('text1').style.color = document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="getColor();">
<div id="div1" onload="getColor();" style="background-color: #fff">
  <h1 id="text1" style="filter: invert(100%)">Sample Text</h1>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Use `<body onload="getColor();">` instead of `div onload`